# PHP run executable on server with parameters arguments

Tags: php, windows, python-2.7

I've got a bit of a mess here.

Windows Server 2008 R1 + IIS6 + PHP5.3.10

I have a PHP script which connects to a small, local mssql database, performs a search and puts the results into variables. There are 6 columns in the db though only 4 of them are worth passing.

I have a console python program (in 2.7 flavor) on this server. It takes 4 arguments (target email address, subject, body and key (key is a 64 alphanum string). This python program then puts all of this into an HTML template (which is defined in the program itself) and emails it off to the target.

OK - both of these individually work! Now the fun part. Am I able to have PHP launch this python program, which sits in the same directory as the php script and pass off four arguments/parameters to it? The arguments/parameters may have spaces in them.

Comment: Have you taken a look on `exec()` or `shell_exec()`?

Comment: I have seen this example exec('nameofexecutable.exe para1 para2 para3'); but when I use this the program never seems to execute. I though perhaps this would be because it would execute as whatever identity IIS was using (network) but the item never appears in task manager (when it should normally take near 20 seconds to complete - I purposefully created waits in parts of the python program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use `exec()` or `shell_exec()` to run your python script. Also use `escapeshellarg()` and `escapeshellcmd()` as appropriate to sanitize your input. This may look like this:

```
$escaped_cmd = escapeshellcmd('nameofexecutable.exe para1 para2 para3');
exec($escaped_cmd);
```

Of course you need proper permissions to run the executable.

Comment: Gotcha. Actually, there are no forms/user input for this. This PHP script is called when a user clicks either ACCEPT or DENY in an HTML email message. Either button launches a web browser to site.com/nameofphpscript.php?key=<random 64 digit alphanum>. PHP then looks to see if the key exists in the db and if it does it takes the information and dishes it out to the python program to be emailed out internally within the company. I am thinking this would probably be a bit more secure.

Comment: Assuming the setup is correct, is this the right syntax? exec('nameofexecutable.exe para1 para2 para3'); ??

Comment: @PatrickAlexson More or less. I updated my answer.  You would need to make sure have permissions to run the file and that the file is executable.

Comment: Thank you! I would mark both answers if I could but since I cannot I will mark both as helpful

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). It will run a command on the console and return the last line of output. If you want all of the output, the optional second argument will give you that.

And as Erty says, sanitize your inputs. DO NOT EVER EVER EVER pass user-supplied data directly to the command line.

Comment: just please be sure to SANITIZE YOUR INPUTS!

Comment: Thank you! I would mark both answers if I could but since I cannot I will mark both as helpful